# Update WHERE NOT EXISTS problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This query gives an error whenever there are more than 1 record that exists in tbl1 and not in tbl1_temp

How can I fix this so that for every record that does not exist in tbl1_temp, update the corresponding record's status in tbl1

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET Status = 'Finished' 
WHERE id = (SELECT id 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tbl1_temp 
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl1_temp.id))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET Status = 'Finished' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tbl1_temp 
    WHERE tbl1.id = tbl1_temp.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use NOT EXISTS directly

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET Status = 'Finished' 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl1_temp
                WHERE tbl1.id = tbl1_temp.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The equality operator works only for a single value, not for multiple values, hence the error. So instead of equation, use `IN`:

```
... WHERE id IN (SELECT ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET Status = 'Finished' 
WHERE id **IN** (SELECT id 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tbl1_temp 
WHERE tbl1.id = tbl1_temp.id))
```